# Conditions under which the integral of an exponential function over $\mathbb{R}^k$ is finite

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration, analysis, gaussian-integral

## Theorem

Let $C$ be a normalization constant and $\lambda_1,\ldots, \lambda_k$ a number sequence.

The integral over $\mathbb{R}^k$:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^k} C \exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_iy^2_i\right\} dy_1\cdots dy_k
$$
be finite only if **all the $\lambda$'s are positive**.

## Question

Can this be easily shown? I have no policy at all. Please give me ideas or guidelines.

## Background

We consider $X\sim k$-variate normal distribution, the density of which is of the form
$$
C\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^k a_{ij}(x_i-\xi_i)(x_j-\xi_j)\right\}.
$$
In addition, we consider the orthogonal transformation $\underline{y} = Q \underline{x}, \underline{\eta} = Q \underline{\xi}$.
Then, it is known that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^k a_{ij}(x_i-\xi_i)(x_j-\xi_j) = \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i (y_i - \eta_i)^2
$$
holds.
Therefore, the density of $\underline{Y} = Q\underline{X}$ is
$$
C \exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_i (y_i - \eta_i)^2\right\}.
$$

Comment: Hint: Use iterated integration over the finite region $[-a,a]^k$ and take the limit as $a\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integrand is positive for any choice of $\{\lambda_1,...,\lambda_k\}$ so [Tonelli-Fubini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli%27s_theorem_for_non-negative_measurable_functions) holds. If all $\lambda_\ell>0$, then
$$\begin{aligned}\int_{\mathbb{R}^k}e^{-\sum_{1\leq \ell \leq k}\lambda_\ell y_\ell^2/2}d\lambda^k&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}(...)\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\sum_{1\leq \ell \leq k}\lambda_\ell y_\ell^2/2}dy_1(...)d y_k\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}(...)\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\sum_{2\leq \ell \leq k}\lambda_\ell y_\ell^2/2}\bigg(\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\lambda_1 y_1^2/2}dy_1\bigg)dy_2(...)d y_k\\
&=(2\pi)^{1/2}\lambda_1^{-1/2}\int_{\mathbb{R}}(...)\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\sum_{2\leq \ell \leq k}\lambda_\ell y_\ell^2/2}dy_2(...)d y_k\\
&=(...)\\
&=(2\pi)^{k/2}\prod_{1\leq \ell\leq k}\lambda_\ell^{-1/2}<\infty
\end{aligned}$$
Suppose there exists $\lambda_h\leq 0$. Wlog $h=1$. Then
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^k}e^{-\sum_{1\leq \ell \leq k}\lambda_\ell y_\ell^2/2}d\lambda^k=\int_{\mathbb{R}}(...)\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\sum_{2\leq \ell \leq k}\lambda_\ell y_\ell^2/2}\underbrace{\bigg(\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\lambda_1 y_1^2/2}dy_1\bigg)}_{=\infty}dy_2(...)d y_k=\infty
\end{aligned}$$